# Add AngularJS filter in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Seems like a very basic question but I can't get the syntax right,
my json array

```
{"varremise":[
    {"name":"Devise",
     "vars":["EUR","USD","Notprovided","Notprovided"]
    },...
}
```

Can anyone help to get the list of vars without Notprovided String, i have write this but it dont work

```
 <option ng-repeat="ite in item.vars | filter:{ vars: '!Notprovided'}" value="{{ite}}">{{ite}}</option>
```

Comment: What's the `item` variable?

Comment: <div class="col-md-6" ng-repeat="item in varremise">

Comment: So you're filtering `item.vars`, that's to say `["EUR","USD","Notprovided","Notprovided"]`. Do you see where is you error now?

Comment: i havn't understant, can you explain more please

Comment: Have a look again: your filter is `{vars: '…'}`, but you're filtering `["EUR","USD","Notprovided","Notprovided"]`. Do you see what's going on, now?

Comment: when i change vars: by item.vars: it dont return any String

Comment: I'm giving up. Just use `item.vars | filter:'!Notprovided'`.

Comment: Please share the item.vars

Comment: Also make sure vars: '!Notprovided'  - the 'vars' property is defined in the 'item.vars' object.Then it will work.Object given to filter map the property name.

Comment: i have added this :      <option ng-repeat="ite in item.vars | filter:{ ite: !Notprovided }" value="{{ite}}">{{ite}}</option> but nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best and shortest way:

```
<option ng-repeat="ite in item.vars | filter:'!Notprovided'" value="{{ite}}">{{ite}}</option>
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer sir Alpha-Centuri, but It dont work

Comment: edited it, most probably you were not adding proper controller in my previous answer

Comment: @darkman, but in comment you say Blackhole, that this don't work

Comment: aay excuse me, i havent well see his answer, i thinked thats propse me  **item.vars:'!Notprovided'**  excuse me @Blackhole